# Foursquare API - perform custom searches

Tags: api, foursquare

I have read the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) on this without any luck. Basically what I want to accomplish, is being able to search after a term - say "food", and get back a list over places where you are likely to get/buy food. If I use the `query` in my request, it matches the search word against venue name, which is not what I want.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which search endpoint are you trying to use, /venues/search or /venues/explore?

For your situation it sounds like you should use /venues/explore with a url param of section=food